# "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: super" exception - bug in compiler?

Tags: java, javac, java-9, nosuchfieldexception

The following code written in Java-9 being run gives me a very weird and funny exception in **runtime**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: super
    at A$C.test(A.java:15)
    at A.main(A.java:5)
```

The code:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new C().test();
    }

    interface B {
        private void test() {
        }
    }

    static class C implements B {
        void test() {
            B.super.test();
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering: is it designed so, or ideally this code shouldn't be compiled, and therefore this is a compiler bug? (I personally believe that this is a **bug**).

**UPD**: Submitted a bug,  ID : 9052188

**UPD-2**: It looks like `B.super.test()` is generally a valid construction, because if `test()` method is `default` than it works fine. This fact just makes things more complicated.

Comment: Guessing here: A) this code is invalid (the B super interface is an interface, thus there is no point in deferring to an **implementation** of a method within that) and B) yeah, compiler bug. So the reasonable thing to do: go write a bug tracker issue ;-)

Comment: Of course, it is a compiler bug. A program that compiles without errors and is not manipulated afterwards should never get a `NoSuchFieldError` at runtime (unless creating and throwing it itself explicitly), regardless of whether the source code is valid or invalid.

Comment: @Holger theoretically it could be also JVM bug if such a code is allowed according to JLS 9. But I am to reluctant to delve into it :)

Comment: @DwB I have no explicit module definitions

Comment: @GhostCat: not exactly. `B` has a `private` method, which is accessible because it’s a nested class and we’re within the same top level class. But I suppose, `B.super.test()` is not the right syntax for it (but it is the right syntax for invoking `default` methods). In contrast, `((B)this).test()` is definitely valid syntax and also works correctly.

Comment: @Andremoniy well, yes, without going deeper, we could assume that this could be a JVM bug, but well, I went deeper. `super` access is never implementing using a field called `super`, further, when calling the method via `((B)this).test()`, it works smoothly. The only remaining question is whether `B.super.test()` is valid and should get compiled like `((B)this).test()` or whether it is not valid and should be rejected by the compiler. I tend to the latter.

Comment: @Holger, a funny thing is that `B.super.test()` is valid construction if `test()` is  a `default` method :)

Comment: Now I tend to consider this as a JVM bug, because it generally should be possible access `test()` method even it is private within the scope of this inner class.

Comment: @Andremoniy I tend to agree with you here, a very interesting finding

Comment: I [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48175532/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-super-exception-bug-in-compiler?noredirect=1#comment83331209_48175532) that `Interface.super.method()` is the right way to invoke `default` methods, but as far as I can see in the JLS, it is *only* for invoking `default` methods. Regarding the accessibility, the JVM never allows accessing `private` methods by other (ordinary) classes. That's why the compiler generates these synthetic `access$n` methods for nested classes. A `NoSuchFieldError` is not an indicator that the JVM denied method access.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the end this issue was admitted as a bug by the Java Developer Support team, here is a link: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8194847